# Starting a process over ssh using bash and then killing it on sigint

Tags: bash, ssh, signals

I want to start a couple of jobs on different machines using ssh. If the user then interrupts the main script I want to shut down all the jobs gracefully.

Here is a short example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "aborted" SIGINT SIGTERM
aborted() {
    kill -SIGTERM $bash2_pid
    exit
}

ssh -t remote_machine /foo/bar.sh &
bash2_pid=$!
wait
```

However the bar.sh process is still running the remote machine. If I do the same commands in a terminal window it shuts down the process on the remote host.

Is there an easy way to make this happen when I run the bash script? Or do I need to make it log on to the remote machine, find the right process and kill it that way?

edit:
Seems like I have to go with option B, killing the remotescript through another ssh connection

So no I want to know how do I get the remotepid?
I've tried a something along the lines of :

```
remote_pid=$(ssh remote_machine '{ /foo/bar.sh & } ; echo $!')
```

This doesn't work since it blocks.

How do I wait for a variable to print and then "release" a subprocess?

Comment: Have you tried a trap in your remote script? Perhaps SIGHUP?

Comment: I've tried to trap all the signals I can think of without any success...

I guess I'll just have to ssh to the remote machine again and run kill on the script, but then I need the pid of the remote process...

Comment: Try `pkill` if that's the way you're going to go. Crude but usually effective.

Comment: The problem is that I might have multiple instances of the script running. I just want to kill the remote instances I'm 100% sure are spawned from the locale instance I'm killing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It would definitely be preferable to keep your cleanup managed by the ssh that starts the process rather than moving in for the kill with a second ssh session later on.

When ssh is attached to your terminal; it behaves quite well.  However, detach it from your terminal and it becomes (as you've noticed) a pain to signal or manage remote processes.  You can shut down the link, but not the remote processes.

That leaves you with one option:  Use the link as a way for the remote process to get notified that it needs to shut down.  The cleanest way to do this is by using blocking I/O.  Make the remote read input from ssh and when you want the process to shut down; send it some data so that the remote's reading operation unblocks and it can proceed with the cleanup:

```
command & read; kill $!
```

This is what we would want to run on the remote.  We invoke our command that we want to run remotely; we read a line of text (blocks until we receive one) and when we're done, signal the command to terminate.

To send the signal from our local script to the remote, all we need to do now is send it a line of text.  Unfortunately, Bash does not give you a lot of good options, here.  At least, not if you want to be compatible with bash < 4.0.

With bash 4 we can use co-processes:

```
coproc ssh user@host 'command & read; kill $!'
trap 'echo >&"${COPROC[1]}"' EXIT
...
```

Now, when the local script exits (don't trap on `INT`, `TERM`, etc.  Just `EXIT`) it sends a new line to the file in the second element of the `COPROC` array.  That file is a pipe which is connected to `ssh`'s `stdin`, effectively routing our line to `ssh`.  The remote command reads the line, ends the `read` and `kill`s the command.

Before bash 4 things get a bit harder since we don't have co-processes.  In that case, we need to do the piping ourselves:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mysshcommand
ssh user@host 'command & read; kill $!' < /tmp/mysshcommand &
trap 'echo > /tmp/mysshcommand; rm /tmp/mysshcommand' EXIT
```

This should work in pretty much any bash version.

Comment: This should work. The script need to run on bash 3.2 so I'll have to make my own piping. The normal case is that the remote process ends normally so I can't rely on the trap to do the clean up of the fifo. (it could if I had them all in a list and did the clean up at the end of the program, but I'd rather remove them as soon as I'm done with them).

Comment: This kinda works but the problem comes now if the program ends normally: the read invocation still needs an input to end.  Any ideas how to cover both cases?

Comment: @jkp: EXIT triggers when the program ends normally too.  It should cover both cases.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
ssh -tt host command </dev/null &
```

When you kill the local ssh process, the remote pty will close and SIGHUP will be sent to the remote process.

Comment: This is not ideal for scripting, especially when piping the script to ssh, it will cause it to print the output line by line as if it was an interactive terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the answer by lhunath and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71205/background-process-pipe-input I came up with this script

run.sh:

```
#/bin/bash
log="log"                                                                                 
eval "$@" \&                                                                              
PID=$!                                                                                    
echo "running" "$@" "in PID $PID"> $log                                                   
{ (cat <&3 3<&- >/dev/null; kill $PID; echo "killed" >> $log) & } 3<&0                              
trap "echo EXIT >> $log" EXIT                                                             
wait $PID
```

The difference being that this version kills the process when the connection is closed, but also returns the exit code of the command when it runs to completion.

```
 $ ssh localhost ./run.sh true; echo $?; cat log
 0
 running true in PID 19247
 EXIT

 $ ssh localhost ./run.sh false; echo $?; cat log
 1
 running false in PID 19298
 EXIT

 $ ssh localhost ./run.sh sleep 99; echo $?; cat log
 ^C130
 running sleep 99 in PID 20499
 killed
 EXIT

 $ ssh localhost ./run.sh sleep 2; echo $?; cat log
 0
 running sleep 2 in PID 20556
 EXIT
```

For a one-liner:

```
 ssh localhost "sleep 99 & PID=\$!; { (cat <&3 3<&- >/dev/null; kill \$PID) & } 3<&0; wait \$PID"
```

For convenience:

```
 HUP_KILL="& PID=\$!; { (cat <&3 3<&- >/dev/null; kill \$PID) & } 3<&0; wait \$PID"
 ssh localhost "sleep 99 $HUP_KILL"
```

Note: kill 0 may be preferred to kill $PID depending on the behavior needed with regard to spawned child processes. You can also kill -HUP or kill -INT if you desire.

Update:
A secondary job control channel is better than reading from stdin.

```
ssh -n -R9002:localhost:8001 -L8001:localhost:9001 localhost ./test.sh sleep 2
```

Set job control mode and monitor the job control channel:

```
set -m
trap "kill %1 %2 %3" EXIT
(sleep infinity | netcat -l 127.0.0.1 9001) &
(netcat -d 127.0.0.1 9002; kill -INT $$) &
"$@" &
wait %3
```

Finally, here's another approach and a reference to a bug filed on openssh:
https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396#c14

This is the best way I have found to do this. You want something on the server side that attempts to read stdin and then kills the process group when that fails, but you also want a stdin on the client side that blocks until the server side process is done and will not leave lingering processes like <(sleep infinity) might.

```
ssh localhost "sleep 99 < <(cat; kill -INT 0)" <&1
```

It doesn't actually seem to redirect stdout anywhere but it does function as a blocking input and avoids capturing keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for bash 3.2:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mysshcommand
ssh user@host 'command & read; kill $!' < /tmp/mysshcommand &
trap 'echo > /tmp/mysshcommand; rm /tmp/mysshcommand' EXIT
```

doesn't work. The ssh command is not on the ps list on the "client" machine. Only after I echo something into the pipe will it appear in the process list of the client machine. The process that appears on the "server" machine would just be the command itself, not the read/kill part.

Writing again into the pipe does not terminate the process.

So summarizing, I need to write into the pipe for the command to start up, and if I write again, it does not kill the remote command, as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider mounting the remote file system and run the script from the master box. For instance, if your kernel is compiled with fuse (can check with the following):

```
/sbin/lsmod | grep -i fuse
```

You can then mount the remote file system with the following command:

```
sshfs user@remote_system: mount_point
```

Now just run your script on the file located in mount_point.

Comment: the purpose of the real script is to distribute the work across a handful of slave machines, so this wouldn't work for me..