# gracefully close ssh and exit net::ssh::perl when SIGINT

Tags: perl, ssh, event-handling, signals

I am connecting to a remote host and executing a command which does not exit (tail -f logfile)

I am registering a handler and writing the output to a log file.
This is working fine
But I want to press Control+C on the main program and it should stop the command on remote machine and close the ssh connection gracefully

So I am registering a signal handler for SIGINT

Need the code which I need to put in the subroutine

The below code is inside a function which is called from forked child

```
#!/ats/bin/perl

use Net::SSH::Perl;
use File::Path;
use Text::CSV_XS;

chomp ($progName = `basename $0`);

if (@ARGV != 1 ) {
        print "usage: perl $progName <tc_id>\n";
        exit;
}

$tc_id = shift;
$file = "config.prop";
$log_dir = "logs/";


#$SIG{INT}=\&close_write;

sub close_write
{
#-- write it to file
print "\nInside END block\n";
#open FH, ">$log_file";
#print $log_file;
#print FH @out;
#$thr->kill('INT');
#close $ssh->sock;
#undef $ssh;
exit 1;
}

# Read the configuration file and populate the Hash
$index = 0;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, eol => $/ });
 open my $io, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";
 while (my $row = $csv->getline ($io)) {
    next if (${$row}[0] =~ m/^#/);  #Ignore comments
    next if (${$row}[0] =~ m/^\s*$/);   #Ignore blank lines
    ($logHashArray->[$index]->{host}, $logHashArray->[$index]->{user}, $logHashArray->[$index]->{pass}, $logHashArray->[$index]->{cmd}, $logHashArray->[$index]->{log_file}) = @$row;
    $index++;
 }


# Append "/" at the end of the directory if it does not exist
unless ($log_dir =~ m/\/$/) {
        $log_dir = $log_dir . "/";
        print "LogDir: $log_dir\n";
        }
# Check if the log directory exists, if not, create it
if (-e $log_dir) {
        unless (-d $log_dir) {
                die "File exists but is not directory";
                }
        }
else {
        # don't forget to check mkdir's failure
        print "Directory $log_dir does not exist... Creating it\n";
        mkpath($log_dir, 0777) or die "Can't make directory: $!";
        }



foreach $logHash (@{$logHashArray}){
        #print "LogHash Index $logHash\n";
        $logHash->{log_file} = $tc_id . "_" . $logHash->{host} . "_" .$logHash->{log_file};
        $logHash->{cmd} = $logHash->{cmd} . " | tee /tmp/" . $logHash->{log_file};
        $logHash->{log_dir} = $log_dir;

        #$logHash->{thr}=threads->new(\&connect_get_logs, $logHash);

        $logHash->{pid} = fork();

        if ($logHash->{pid}){
            # Parent
            push(@childs, $logHash->{pid});
        }
        elsif ($pid == 0){
            # Child
            connect_get_logs($logHash);
        }
        else {
            die "couldn’t fork: $!\n";
            }

while (($key, $value) = each(%{$logHash})){
     print $key."=>".$value."\n";
}

}

#$SIG{INT}=\&close_write;
#$thr=threads->new(\&connect_get_logs, $logHash);

foreach (@childs) {
    waitpid($_, 0);
    }


#print "Waiting...";
#while(1) {sleep 1;}

#$thr->join;


sub connect_get_logs{

$SIG{INT}= sub {
        print "Inside INT block\n"; ### Need proper code here
        close $ssh->sock;
        undef $ssh;
        };

my $logHash = shift;

while (($key, $value) = each(%{$logHash})){
     print $key."=>".$value."\n";
}
my $stdout;
my $stderr;
my $exit;

#-- setup a new connection
print "Logging in to $logHash->{host}...";
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($logHash->{host}, debug => 0, protocol => '2', options => ["PasswordAuthentication yes", "BatchMode yes",
                    "PubkeyAuthenticaion no", "RhostsAuthentication no", "RhostsRSAAuthentication no", "RSAAuthentication no", "DSAAuthentication no"]);

#-- authenticate
$ssh->login($logHash->{user}, $logHash->{pass});
print "Logged In\n";

#-- Create or Overwrite the log files
open LOG_FILE, ">", "$logHash->{log_dir}$logHash->{log_file}" or die $!;

#-- register a handler
$ssh->register_handler("stdout", sub {
        my($channel, $buffer) = @_;
        $str = $buffer->bytes;
        #push @out, $str;
        print LOG_FILE $str;
        #print $str;
});

#$SIG{INT}=\&close_write;

#-- execute the command
($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($logHash->{cmd});

print "Error: $stderr";

}
```

create a config.prop file in the csv format

host/ip,username,password,command (tail -F /full/path/to/logfile),filename to save as

Comment: **executing a command which does not exit (tail -f logfile)**, you mean that tail isn't installed or logfile doesn't exist?

Comment: both exist, I meant it will not exit or terminate since it is tail -f filename

Comment: @tuxuday: He means that his call of `tail` does never stop, because it is called with `-f` and needs CTRL + C or an `INT` signal to stop.

Comment: How about adding a little more code so we can try it ourselves. Please [edit] the question so that there is a small, working example in it. You can use dummy connection data. We should all have some kind of machine that we can SSH to.

Comment: @simbabque added the full code.

Comment: Please, add `use strict; use warnings;'

Comment: You have a typo in `"PubkeyAuthenticaion no"`: `s/ticaion/tication/`

Comment: @dolmen it is able to login to the server, so `"PubkeyAuthenticaion no"` may not be the problem for this.

Comment: @dolmen I will add  `use strict; use warnings` and see what warn/errors i get

Comment: @dolmen I have added strict and warnings and corrected those errors. Still, it is not stopping the processes on remote host which are started using $ssh->cmd

Answer (score 2):

The trick is invoking ssh with `-t` (or possibly `-tt`).

By default, ssh allocates a pty on the remote machine only for interactive login shells (ie, not when invoking a command on the remote).  `-t` forces ssh to allocate a pty, even when executing a remote command.  You can see the effect:

```
$ ssh starquake tty
not a tty
```

vs

```
$ ssh -t starquake tty
/dev/pts/1
Connection to starquake closed.
```

ssh [apparently will pass on signals to the remote process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235180/starting-a-process-over-ssh-using-bash-and-then-killing-it-on-sigint) when attached to the terminal, but not otherwise.

Comment: That works when you use `ssh` to connect to the remote host (or some module wrapping it). With Net::SSH::Perl allocation of a tty can be done setting `use_pty => 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the process id of the call to `tail -f`, you can send it an `INT` signal from the command line with:

```
kill -s INT <pid>
```

What you need to do in your `$SIG{'INT'}` in your main program is let it also send an `INT` through the `Net::SSH` connection. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I cannot get the pid of the tail -f as it is running on remote machine. When I put   `close $ssh->sock; inside the SIG{INT}` subroutine, it says `Can't call method "sock" on an undefined value`

Comment: Your `$ssh` is lexical and the `SIG{INT}` cannot see it. Either make `$ssh` global (not really recommended) or try putting the assignment of the `SIG{INT}` sub in the same block as the `my $ssh`.

Comment: it is indeed in the same block as $ssh

Comment: Somebody answer this question please

Answer (score 0):

$ssh->login(); #to login in a ssh session

$ssh ->close; #to logout from an ssh session

enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can see an alternative solution that uses SFTP instead of SSH to continuously read from a remote file: [sftp_tail.pl](https://metacpan.org/source/SALVA/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.77/samples/sftp_tail.pl).

The remote `sftp-server` process will exit when the connection is closed (for instance, because you press Ctrl-C) without requiring any further action on your part.

Answer (score -1):

The full procedure to login, access and close an ssh session inside the perl.

```
            my $host = 192.168.0.1;

            my $username = "example";

            my $passwd  = "example";

            my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
            host => $host,
            user => $username,
            password => $passwd,
            timeout => 20,
            );
            $ssh->login();
            $ssh->exec("command_to_be_executed_in_ssh\r\n");
            $ssh ->close;
```